# Take the items of a json file separately

Tags: python, json, file

Hey guys so I am trying to read a Json file and write a specific item of it in a list. But the json file is in single quotes so I get the error.

**simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)**

I tried to convert the json file from single quotes to double but it didn't work (I also saw the other stackoverflow questions about this but didn't work for me). Because I tried it with str.replace. or json dumps etc. And it always had a different problem. My code is this:

```
messages = []

with open("commitsJson.json","r", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for p in data['items']:
       messages.append(p['message'])
       authors.write(p['message']+"\r\n")
       print(p['message'])
```

So the expected result is to read the json file and write specific items of it into a file or list, etc...

**EDIT:**
Sample of json file:

```
{'total_count': 3, 'incomplete_results': False, 'items': [{'url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada', 
'sha': '2131932103812jdskfsl', 'node_id': 'asl;dkas;ldjasldasio1203', 
'html_url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada', 
'comments_url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada',
 'commit': {'url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada', 'message': 'Initial commit 1'
```

> Something like that. Basically a github api response but with single quotes instead of double...

**Desired output would be to get the 'message' Items of all the json file in to another file like:**

```
Initial commit 1
Initial commit 2
Initial commit 3
Initial commit 4
Initial commit 5
Initial commit 6
Initial commit 7
....
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

Comment: Sample of your `json` file?

Comment: Yeah sure second...

Comment: Along with your desired output, please.

Comment: Your file does not contain any `json`. It looks more like a serialised `dict`

Comment: You are write. I get this type <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>. But my file is .json why do i get this kind of class?

Comment: Perhaps you should address the problem of how the `commitsJson.json` file is produced. If this were `json` to start with your code might start working.

Comment: @AlexRika: you can find us in chat. See the link below the answer from DirtyBit.

Comment: @quamrana hey I am in chat can we talk?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that json expects double quotes to surround strings

Using `ast.literal_eval` on the file contents:

**commitJson.json**:

```
{
  'total_count': 3, 'incomplete_results': False, 'items': [{'url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada',
  'sha': '2131932103812jdskfsl', 'node_id': 'asl;dkas;ldjasldasio1203',
  'html_url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada',
  'comments_url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada',
   'commit': {'url': 'https://gits-20.bkf.sda.eu/api/v3/repos/repo/name/commits/2189312903jsadada', 'message': 'Initial commit 1'}}]
}
```

**Hence**:

```
import ast
with open("commitJson.json","r", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = ast.literal_eval(json_file.read())

for elem in data['items']:
    for e in elem['commit']:
       if 'message' in e:
           print(elem['commit'][e])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Initial commit 1
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
print([elem['commit'][e] for e in elem['commit'] if 'message' in e for elem in data['items']])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['Initial commit 1']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191600/discussion-on-answer-by-dirtybit-take-the-items-of-a-json-file-separately).